# Tomcat v9.0 server is returning HTTP Status 404 – Not Found error

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, tomcat9

When I am trying to run a servlet in which I am just establishing a general Database Connection it shows me this error

```
HTTP Status 404 – Not Found


Type Status Report

Message The requested resource [/Setting_Up_JNDI/Demo] is not available

Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.


Apache Tomcat/9.0.52
```

Even though I have the file in my project.
Please have a look at my servlet

```
@WebServlet("/Demo")
public class Demo extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
      private DataSource dataSource;
      @Resource(name="jdbc/project")
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
        java.sql.Connection connect=null;
        java.sql.Statement stmt=null;
        ResultSet rs=null;
        try {
            connect = dataSource.getConnection();
            String query ="Select * from users";
            stmt=connect.createStatement();
            rs=stmt.executeQuery(query);
            while(rs.next()) {
                out.print("</br>"+ rs.getString("email"));
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }

}
```

Here is my contex.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
    <Resource name="jdbc/project" 
              auth="Container"
              type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
              username="saboor" 
              password="baba2011"
              driverClassName="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
              url="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/saboor_db?useSSL=false"
              maxActive="25" 
              maxIdle="5"/>

</Context>
```

Even though I have the required files in my orject structure the strange error keeps popping up.
P.S I can't access **http://localhost:8080/**
Here is my project structure

[image: My project structure]

Comment: The error indicates that your project is either not deployed, or the URL you're using is wrong. There is no conclusive proof here that the problem is with the JDBC connection or not. Please provide a [mre], and check the Tomcat logs if maybe it contains exceptions or deployment errors.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Ok lemme try..
It gives me this error too...